# Getting exception while accessing ConnectionString from appSettings.json in Asp.Net Core 3.3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I have added the code in the startup.cs file:

```
services.Configure<MongoConnnection>(options =>
            {
                options.ConnectionString
                    = Configuration.GetSection("MongoConnection:ConnectionString").Value;
                options.Database
                    = Configuration.GetSection("MongoConnection:Database").Value;
            });
```

appSetings.json

```
{
  "MongoConnection": {
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    "Database": "Gyming"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

In UserRepository.cs

```
private IMongoCollection<User> _user;
public UserRepository(IOptions<MongoConnnection> settings)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient(settings.Value.ConnectionString);
            if (client != null)
                _database = client.GetDatabase(settings.Value.Database);
            _user = database.GetCollection<User>("users");
        }
```

MongoConnection.cs

```
public class MongoConnnection : IMongoConnnection
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public string Database { get; set; }
    }
```

But getting null value in ConnectionString while debuging

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

Please, Seniors, help me out as soon as possible

Comment: See (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configuration.getsection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).  CustomSection customSection section = Configuration.GetSection("MongoConnection") as CustomSesction;
string connectionStr = section.ConnectionString;

Comment: You are checking for null value then where you are getting nullException.

Comment: @D.J. At this point, I am getting null settings.Value.ConnectionString. Getting null for ConnectionString

Comment: Your code works just fine for me. Are you sure you have implemented `MongoConnnection` class correctly?

Comment: @Crowcoder yes I implemented correctly.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and it works. The only other thing I can think of is to check if you are also loading that configuration from another appsettings file (like appsettings.Development.json) or another configuration provider that is overriding appsettings.json.